# React changing route breaks height with layout

Tags: html, reactjs, height, react-router, document-body

I have a React application where if I change the route to a page with a small height the entire `body` doesn't have a max height for the window (the `html` does have full height).

I have a standard `index.html` setup here

```
<html>
    <body>
       <div id="app"></div>
       <script src="client.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then here's my `App.js` file:

```
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"
import {Router, hashHistory} from "react-router"

import routes from "./Routes"

const app = document.getElementById('app')

ReactDOM.render((
    <Router history={hashHistory} routes={routes()}>
    </Router>
), app)
```

And here's my `Routes.js` file:

```
import React from "react"
import {Route, IndexRoute} from "react-router"

import Layout from "./Layout"

import About from "./pages/About"
import Home from "./pages/Home"
import NotFound from "./pages/NotFound"
import Register from "./pages/Register"
import SignIn from "./pages/SignIn"
import Terms from "./pages/Terms"

export default() => {
    return (
        <Route name="root" path="/" component={Layout}>
            <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
            <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
            <Route path="/signin" component={SignIn}/>
            <Route path="/register" component={Register}/>
            <Route path="/terms" component={Terms}/>
            <Route path="*" component={NotFound}/>
        </Route>
    )
}
```

Finally here's my `Layout.js`:

```
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react"
import DevTool from 'mobx-react-devtools'

import Control from "./components/layout/Control"
import Footer from "./components/layout/Footer"
import Header from "./components/layout/Header"
import Sidebar from "./components/layout/Sidebar"

export default class Layout extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const { location } = this.props

        return (
            <div className="wrapper">
                <DevTool /> {/* Remove for PRODUCTION */}
                <Header />
                <Sidebar />
                {this.props.children}
                <Footer />
                <Control />
                <div className="control-sidebar-bg"></div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

All my routes go to pages with very little content so it doesn't cover the full page. In every case the entire `body` height wraps to the height of the content while the `html` remains 100% of with window.

I've tried debugging on everything. There's no padding or margin on the body or html rendered by inspecting the elements. I've also tried adding `height` and `min-height` `100%` attributes to the `body` tags with inline styling and still didn't get any decent results.

The page automatically fixes itself as soon as the window resizes or I reload the page but that eliminates a lot of the reason to why I am using React.

Any ideas on what could fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get a fix, this is quite a specific problem (which I've gather from the lack of response). But in-case anyone else stumbled across a problem like this.

All of my pages components had the following render:

```
export default class About extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="content-wrapper">
                {/* All my about code goes in here */}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I ended up removing the `content-wrapper` classNames from all the page container dividers and did the following to the `Layout` page:

```
export default class Layout extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const { location } = this.props

        return (
            <div className="wrapper">
                <DevTool /> {/* Remove for PRODUCTION */}
                <Header />
                <Sidebar />
                <div className="content-wrapper">
                    {this.props.children}
                </div>
                <Footer />
                <Control />
                <div className="control-sidebar-bg"></div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

This solved all my problems :)