# Height of body doesn't resize after moving to other pages

Tags: css, reactjs, react-router, single-page-application

I'm developing a single page web app using React & React Router, and now facing a problem as follows.

When the app shows a long list of items, the length of body is extended and scrolling bar shows up (that's ok). Then you move to the other page which I expect the body to be 100vh (the same length as viewport ), and the result is, the length of body remains as long as before and not changed to 100vh.

What I want is when you move to other pages, the body resize according to the height of the current page.

Does anyone have the same issue and have some solution to this?

Comment: Maybe this can help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40265277/react-changing-route-breaks-height-with-layout

Comment: Any working demo?